# how do make synchronous task as asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
class some{   
let result;

 function asyn addition(){
    if (this.result != 'addition'){   //synchronous
        return this.result;
    }
    else
    result = await do some asynchronous task;   // asynchronous promise using some third party lib.
    return result;
    }
    }
}
```

**Question 1**: Can we implement the sybschronous code in asyn function?

**Question2:** How can I make the synchronous as an asynchronous task so that addition() can work asynchronously?

note: I have to do the task in the same function only.

Comment: mmm, no sense for this, i cant understand.... try to look rx.js

Comment: but don't want to use observable..can't I do with promises?

Comment: you must be responsbale of the state of your app. Delegate this is not a god idea

Comment: I voted to close because your question really isn't clear. You included some code block that (minus the syntax errors) would make your task asynchronous, so what don't you understand about it?

Comment: An `async function` always returns a promise, regardless whether you use `await` or not. It'll just work out of the box and wrap the result of the synchronous operation.

Comment: cool..can you provide an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: Can we implement the sybschronous code in asyn function?

Of cause.

> Question2: How can I make the synchronous as an asynchronous task so that addition() can work asynchronously?

When an `async function` is called, it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), if you omit `async` keyword from a `async function`, you should return a Promise object instead. For example:

```
/* async */ function async_fn() {
    return Promise.resolve('hello');
}

async function main() {
    let msg = await async_fn();
    console.log(msg);
}
```

if you call `main()` above, you'll get the message "hello" in console.

the `await` expression [can only be used inside an async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). so if you omit `async` keyword in an "async" function, you should handle "Promise" by yourself.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

> When an async function is called, it returns a Promise. When the async
>   function returns a value, the Promise will be resolved with the
>   returned value.  When the async function throws an exception or some
>   value, the Promise will be rejected with the thrown value.

so your code is technically equal to:

```
function async_function() {
    return Promise.resolve('hello world');
}

class some {
    result;

    addition() {
        if (this.result != 'addition') {   //synchronous
            return Promise.resolve(this.result);
        } else {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                async_function().then(function (result) {
                    resolve(result); // Promise resolve here (normal return)
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    reject(err); // Promise reject (throw error)
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and because return type of `async_function()` is a `Promise` too, if you don't intend to manipulate its `result` in method `addition()`, you can make this function simpler:

```
class some {
    result;

    addition() {
        if (this.result != 'addition') {   //synchronous
            return Promise.resolve(this.result);
        } else {
            return async_function();
        }
    }
}
```